# distinguish between panel in mouse click

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

if in a form I have 10 panels named in order from 1 to 10 and all of them registered with the same Event myPanel_Click

```
private void myPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

can I retrieve the name of the panel I clicked among those 10 panels?

```
int panelClicked;
private void myPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //not a single clue
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you should be able to cast the sender as a panel and then take the name property.

```
private void myPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel target = sender as Panel;
    if(target != null)
        MessageBox.Show(target.Name);
}
```

Comment: @Fabian Bigler, when you call the method yourself, or sometimes during databinding

Answer (score 0):

```
private void myPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show((Panel)sender.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also us the [Tag Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) to reference your Panels, by assigning your panel number to the respective Tag.

```
private void myPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Panel p = (Panel)sender;
   switch ((int)p.Tag )
   {
       case 1:
           // Your Code for Panel 1
           break;
       case 2:
           // Your Code for Panel 2 
           break;
       // Your other Panels here
       default:
           break;
   }
}
```